# Change pointer to slice of type to another slice of another type

Tags: go, pointers, slice

```
var buf1 []Somestruct1
var buf2 []Somestruct2

var selected_buf //pointer, needs to be declared. I used *int, []interface{}, *[]interface{}, but nothing seems to work so far

changeme := 0
switch changeme {
    case 0:
        // should point to buf1 to mutate it in future
        selected_buf = &buf1
    case 1:
        // should point to buf2 to mutate it in future
        selected_buf = &buf2
}

// examples of use and mutation
len(selected_buf)
selected_buf = append(selected_buf, Somestruct1) // or Somestruct2 depending on pointer
```

I want to refactor some code, but cannot do it because the pointer gaves me variety of errors depending on how I choose to implement it. Previously something like that worked:

```
var newstruct Somestruct3
for i := range buf1 {
    current := buf1[i]
    if current.somefield == someint {
        newstruct.somefield = &current
    }
}
```

And it worked fine. idk what to do. pls help)

"moderators, please, be kind - I'm typing from the phone on the shitty network. thanks"

Comment: What you are trying to do will not work. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need to do this? It is likely that there are other ways that can be achieved.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  Yeah, It's kinda changing the type of the variable "on the fly". We know it's impossible for static-typed langs. I found a solution how to refactor. Somestruct1 and Somestruct2 are connected anyway, so looping through first and nested loop through the second. It's ok. For now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see these two types are going to be merged into one type, so one possible work that can be done is to introduce an interface with possible methods and append it to that interface

```
type testinterface interface {
}

func main() {
    var tmp []Somestruct1
    var tmp2 []Somestruct2
    var tmp3 []testinterface

    tmp3 = append(tmp3, &Somestruct1)
    tmp3 = append(tmp3, &Somestruct2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this next time. The file I worked on is at https://github.com/zhexyez/go-build-html/tree/master . There is no refactor yet. Find case "R", but it has already changed its logic.